# Is there a way to conditionally require a field in a Django Filterset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Let's say I have a Filterset:

```
class AnimalFilter(filters.FilterSet):
     animal_family = filters.CharFilter(required=True)
     is_land_animal = filters.BooleanFilter(required=True)
```

But what if I only want to set `required=True` for one or the other.  Like if someone passes in `animal_family`, I don't need to receive `is_land_animal` or vise versa.

Comment: Um. Animal family == mustelids. Otters? ==birds Penguins?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use something undocumented(?). If you look at the [source of django-filters](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/main/django_filters/filterset.py) you will see that in `__init__` it binds your view's request to self.request.

You can therefore code these filters using `method=` and supply method code to peek in `self.request.GET` when the method gets invoked to see whether the "other" one has been supplied. If so, leave the queryset unmodified.

Both filters `required=False`. If you are determined to prevent neither being supplied, you'd need to check somewhere (in your view's `get` method?) that one or other is in `request.GET` and raise an exception or redirect to an error-view.

All off the top of my head while waiting for a quarter-Terabyte to copy.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set `required=True` then you have to use query_params in your get method and fetch those attributes that you want to show.
Query_params works like a filter.

For example:

```
 def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = self.request.user
    company = user.branch.company
    branch = user.branch
    assetID = self.request.query_params.get('assetID', None)
    if assetID is not None:
        asset_query = Assets.objects.filter(company=company, branch=branch, id=assetID)
        if asset_query.exists():
            asset_detail = YourModel.values('id', 'name', 'asset_id', 'purchase_date').\
                annotate(asset_category_name=F('asset_category__category_name'),
                         asset_user_first_name=F('asset_user__first_name'),
                         asset_user_last_name=F('asset_user__last_name'))
            return Response({'asset_details': asset_detail, 'history': history}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'This AssetID does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response({'message': 'AssetID is required'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST))
```

The API EndPoint will send like this

http://127.0.0.1:8000/**apiName**/?assetID=True

you have to keep in mind what I receive from the endpoint if it's a number then send numbers if it's Boolean then send **TRUE or FALSE** if it's any string then send **string**,